# How to read an opaque value from receipt?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

I have an application which uses auto renewable subscription. I use applicationUsername property of SKMutablePayment to save some information. How can I later read this data from opaque value from receipt?

I try to do it similarly to this solution: 
https://www.objc.io/issues/17-security/receipt-validation/

But when I try to decode opaque value

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:opaqueData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

my `str` variable is empty.

Comment: `opaqueData` may not be transformable into `NSString`. Not all data are UTF8-Encoding compliant. You said you tried the solution given into the link, what did you do exactly beside the NSString translation test?

Comment: I did exactly the same what is in the solution. So for case 4 I have this:                                 `str_ptr = ptr;
                ASN1_get_object(&str_ptr, &str_length, &str_type, &str_xclass, seq_end - str_ptr);
                opaqueData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:(const void *)ptr length:length];
                NSString *newStr1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:opaqueData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: And what's the value of `opaqueData`?

Comment: `opaqueData` is not empty, contains some bytes. But I noticed that `str_type` has different values.